# Angular & Bootstrap main Scrollbar not working

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

I'm currently working on an Angular app with Bootstrap 5. Now I just noticed that the main html/body scrollbar is not working when elements overflow the view. I've tried multiple suggestions already as for example setting a fixed height, setting overflow-y to scroll or auto for body and html, setting overflow for custom divs, none worked. I'm working a lot with ng-templates and ng-containers, so maybe that might be a reason for the scroll bar not showing up.

I don't really know what code parts to show, so please feel free to ask me any code parts to share.

Below is a screenshot of the problem.

[image]

Comment: Comment out all overflow settings in your css files. Also you can check in the Chrome Developer Tools which class is hiding the scrollbars.

Comment: @DaniloKörber only one element with class "card-text" has overflow: hidden, but that one is a child of card div

Answer (score 0):

I had @ionic/angular installed to be able to use the ion-icon HTML tag, and I just saw that it applied a lot of weird stuff to the body tag such as overflow: hidden and more. The weird thing was that I couldn't override the overflow property and that's why I uninstalled @ionic/angular and switched to Bootstrap icons.